# Extracting Time from Date field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, datetime

My data has a date field formatted as "MM/DD/YYY hh:mm:ss". I want to create a new field with just the time in the full "hh:mm:ss" format. I've found how to extract only the hour, only the minute, or only the second, but how do I extract the full time stamp?

I've tried using the Field Calculator function **DatePart("hh:mm:ss",[DateField])**, but to no avail.

Also, should this new field showing only time be a date field, or would it be a string?

Per the possible duplicate question edit; the answer given was to use the "Convert Time Field" tool in ArcMap. However, this tool does not give an Output Time Format option of **hh:mm:ss**

Comment: data format? software used?

Comment: @DPSSpatial I'm using a File Geodatabase file, ArcMap 10.2

Comment: OK this isn't an ArcGIS only support forum so be sure to list the software and data format you're using in your question, and add those tags as well...